# Restart Shell Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, console

Due to company standards I switched from VS Code to it's bigger brother VS Pro.

When using VS Code while coding with Powershell I do have the possibility to restart powershell (within Code). Easy thing, you close the console and Code asks you whether you want to start a new powershell session.

I need to do so to get my latest changes (within my code) to be activated/effective. How does one do that in Visual Studio (no code)?